# Inline edit in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

i have 2 table in which i can add and delete elements .. elements have 2 date  and 1 number field.. So can you give a direction for the easy way to make them editable inline,but they are not only text or number when i click on date it need me to show custom date picker ...But i need to edit only the one date or the number i don't want to edit all the line when i double click it..only that field what i clicked.Thanks :) Btw it is all react directive. 
I need something like that

```
 render: function () {
        var itemMap = this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={item.selected} onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,i)} /></td>
This i want to change with inline edit ->  <td ><FormattedDate value={item.startDate}/></td>
This i want to change with inline edit ->  <td><FormattedDate value={item.endDate}/></td>
This i want to change with inline edit ->  <td>{item.workInHours}</td>
                    <td><label type="button" onClick={this.handleShowModal.bind(this,i)}><img height="30px" src="moliv.jpg"/></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );

        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary center-block" onClick={this.addElem}>Add</button>
                {this.state.list.theList.length > 0 ?  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.putResult}>Put result</button> :null}
                <table className="table scroll2">
                    <thead>
                    <tr className="danger">
                        <th><input  type="checkbox" checked={this.state.allChecked} onClick={this.toggleAll}/></th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {itemMap}

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                {this.state.items.length > 0 ? <button  type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteItems}>Remove</button> : null}
                <Modal parentState={this.state} modalPropsId={this.props.theProps.id} handleHideModal={this.handleHideModal}/>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more details about your code?

Comment: Sure i add it the render function and i wrote what i want to change.

Comment: If you use react, please add the react tag.

Comment: Yea ok , so can you help me.I don't want code just some easy way for inline edit

Comment: In react you should work on the state object. Define an action where you create the new state, for example you add or delete elements in this.state.items. Calling the *setState()* method of the react component, it should do the trick for you.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me i want to edit inline the element of row of the table that table..

Comment: Ok, sorry. The part on working on the *state* object is correct anyway. There are a lot of possibilities. You should bind an event on the *TD* tags that change the state of a flag when pressed. And so show an editable version of your *TD* content. By using *INPUT* fields. For the *FormattedDate* you should use the [DatePicker](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/) component

Comment: Can you give me a little simple example cuz i am new in the react.Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/alexmario74/pen/JKVPpz?editors=0011) you could find a very trivial example of what I told you. I forked a previous reactjs codepen with a table example and add the handle of the editable cell. The example could be very useful for you. And I already provide the DatePicker link too.